# "He knows to draw very well" vs "He knows how to draw very well"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, word-usage, sentence

Which is the more suitable/correct usage-

*He knows to draw very well.*

**or**

*He knows how to draw very well*

(I think it's the second one)

PS: Since I haven't found many *comparing sentences* type questions on the site it would be helpful if you could point me to useful websites/resources to check the same.

Comment: Bothe are potentially correct depending on the context, but possess quite different meanings. Could you supply the context preceding the phrases please? Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work. Welcome to English Language and Usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*He knows how to* do something = he has the knowledge/ability to do it.

*He knows to* do something = he knows that it is necessary/appropriate to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just my personal opinion, to me both sounds just fine. But if someone would say to me "He knows how to draw very well" it sounds as if he knows how to draw very well, but he's not actually drawing / doing it (now or this way).